# Exchange 2010 email via OWA still gives ExRecipNotFound

Tags: exchange-2010, email-bounces, outlook-web-app

I had an email account: info@product.com.

In exchange I had a distribution group product@mycompany.com. 
This distribution group had a few users.

My DNS MX records pointed to my exchange 2010 server.

So sending an email to info@product.com was going to distribution group product@mycompany.com and there it was distributed to a list of users and contacts.

Recently I moved my domainhosting from product.com where I had the possibility to use mailbox forwarders, hosted by them.
I changed my DNS MX records to their server and everything was fine.
emailing to info@product.com now directly goes to my list of users and not anymore via product@mycompany.com.

Email still works fine, I'm happy with the move as it simplifies things for me on my own exchange server.

I deleted user product@mycompany.com from exchange and AD because this was only created to forward.

Now recently I only had webaccess via OWA and I sent an email to info@product.com
Immediately I received an email from Exchange that the email could not be delivered.

> IMCEAEX-_O=MYCOMPANY+20ORGANIZATION_OU=EXCHANGE+20ADMINISTRATIVE+20GROUP+20+28FYDIBOHF23SPDLT+29_CN=RECIPIENTS_CN=producta81@mycompany.com
>
> ## 550 5.1.1 RESOLVER.ADR.ExRecipNotFound; not found

So the situation/problem:
- Sending to info@product.com from external account works fine (even from my outlook at the company).
- Sending to info@product.com from OWA gives 550 5.1.1 not found.

Why does it happen and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

We see this issue sometimes in outlook when mailboxes have been migrated.
You may try to remove the suggestion when typing the recipient adress and ensure to type the address once completely. 
seems that there is additional information about the ad object behind the suggested recipient.

Comment: This seems to work indeed, any idea how I can make it work when the email address is suggested? More details?

Comment: i don't know if there's an automatism for this issue. we just know the manual fix by removing the entry once by hand.

Comment: Internal suggestions don't use the SMTP address, they are using an X.500 address. Therefore adding an X.500 address to the new object will allow auto completes from the old object to be delivered correctly.

Comment: @Sembee interesting, but 'adding to the new object', how do I do this?

(also: no idea yet how that X.500 address works or how to add/configure it :-) )

Comment: This is written for SBS, but applies to any Exchange servers.
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sbs/2009/05/21/cannot-reply-to-old-emails-or-modify-old-calendar-items-after-pst-mail-migration/